# mysql view to contain running status

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm designing a web based time clock for a school for logging in both students and staff.

I have two tables:

```
student_time_clock: student_id (foreign key to student), time_stamp, by_adult_id (foreign key to adult)

staff_time_clock: staff_id (foreign key to staff), time_stamp
```

One of the requirements I've been given is that an observer be able to see the records in one view like the following:

```
+----------+------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| In / Out | Time Stamp | Person Logged in or out | Logged in or out by |
+----------+------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

I can do all but the first column with a union. I can't figure out how to get that first column though. Here's the query I'm using for the union:

```
SELECT stc.entry                             AS "Time Stamp", 
       Concat(s.lastname, ",", s.firstname) AS "Punched", 
       Concat(a.lastname, ",", a.firstname) AS "By" 
FROM   student_time_clock stc, 
       student s, 
       adult a 
WHERE  stc.student_id = s.id 
       AND stc.by_adult_id = a.id 
UNION 
SELECT atc.entry                             AS "at", 
       Concat(a.lastname, ",", a.firstname) AS "Staff", 
       Concat(a.lastname, ",", a.firstname) AS "By" 
FROM   staff_time_clock atc, 
       staff s, 
       adult a 
WHERE  atc.staff_id = s.id 
ORDER  BY "time stamp" DESC;
```

I've tried using a CASE such as:

```
CASE COUNT( entry ) % 2 WHEN 1 THEN "In" WHEN 0 THEN "Out"
```

When that case is there though I only get a single row in the result.

Any suggestions? The front end is in PHP but I'd like to create this as a view in the database

Comment: Where's the rest of your query?

Comment: Updated the question to show my current union query. Not sure how to add the CASE in though.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `UNION` here?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions...

Comment: `UNION` is slower because it tries to remove duplicates. Use `UNION ALL`

Comment: Good to know. I'll Change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better to add a flag column in first table to capture the type or entry i.e. "In" or "Out". This can simplify your query with certain result.

Comment: I've considered that and I may implement it as you suggest. If I can avoid storing data that can be calculated on the fly though I'd prefer it.

Comment: @HudsonHallenbeck Not sure but consider (if applicable) another scenario while going with computation. If there is mess up in one "in" or "out" entry, it will show all wrong results. Putting a bit oriented flag column will not use much of the space but will result into definitive and simpler logic/query.